# Is this considered a split in an LVL beam?

Tags: beam

I'm trying to understand if this constitutes a split in my lvl beam. The line does not go all the way around so that's why I'm confused.

[image]

Extra details, not sure if it helps:

- The beam is 14ft long
- There are 2 of these lvls attached side by side.

Comment: I do not much about LVL beams, but if I saw that, I would think of two pieces butted together.  Common with making wood beams and is okay depending on how it is made and supported.  I would be worried if it is a new crack/seam that was not there before.

Comment: Splits run parallel to wood grain, not perpendicular like yours. LVL lengths are constrained only by shipping constraints. Joints like yours in the individual veneers are the reason why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That’s normal.

Laminated veneer lumber is just that: laminated layers of veneer. What you’re seeing is a butt joint of a layer of veneer.